# Menu de perguntas com problemas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, perguntas, menu

O menu das perguntas está com problemas de aspeto:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Acabei de perceber isso aqui agora também e iria criar um tópico quando encontrei o seu. Será que estão migrando ao novo formato, igual ao do SOão, ou ferram o `css` mesmo? hehe

Comment: Não sei, mas é estranho ser a essa hora do dia...

Comment: Vi isso mais cedo também, porém, depois de um tempo voltou ao normal. E depois de outro tempo voltou a ficar deformado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about that. We accidentally pushed a set of changes earlier that wasn't meant to go public just yet. The change has been reverted, and things should be back to normal.

> Desculpem. Nós colocamos acidentalmente um conjunto de mudanças que ainda não deviam ter vindo a público. Estas mudanças foram revertidas e as coisas devem voltar ao normal.